# Convert bounding box format

Tags: python, annotations, bounding-box, retinanet

I want to use P-DESTRE dataset with retinaNet model

But i have a problem in bonding box format since  the dataset  bounding box format is:

x, y, h, w (Top left column, top left row, height, width)

Where is written on that model bounding box format is
(x1,y1,x2,y2)

Can you let me know how to convert the dataset format into the model format

Answer (score 0):

The conversion you are asking about is completely straightforward:

(x1,y1,x2,y2) = (x, y, x+w, y+h)